# EXECUTE AS on truncate sproc - Incorrect syntax

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm getting an Incorrect syntax when trying to create a stored procedure to truncate a table then reseed it.  Here's my code

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[_TransportZipporah_Purge]

WITH EXECUTE AS owner
AS
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[*tablename*];
GO
 DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.*tablename*', RESEED, 0);
```

As i have got this direct from MSDN I would have thought it would be correct.
Database server i'm using is : SQL Server 2008 v10.0.4064.0

Can anyone help please?
Thanks in advance
Scott

Comment: It was because the server used was 2000 which does not support EXECUTE AS ... As the SPROC is developed on 2008 then had to rethink the query/solution.

Resolved by creating a new user with ddlAdmin permissions to that table only. Therefore omitting the need for the EXECUTE AS. This will ensure that I can have cross sql server edition platform functionality with security still in tact.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is correct - but you cannot have a GO statement inside a proc.

Comment: I've removed the GO from SPROC and still get Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXECUTE'.